# Programmatically find Netty port spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix

I would like to know how I can programmatically find the netty port while a spring boot 2 + spring cloud Finchley application is starting up?

I am running the service in a docker container on AWS in EC2 container service - I therefore set server.port=0, and cannot use this property to find the actual port used.

Answer (score 2):

In spring-boot 2 you can use `@LocalServerPort` to wire the dynamic port used
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/server/LocalServerPort.html